# Really strange PHP behavior with AJAX with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Well, my problems is a little wierd,

I have an AJAX Request to get just a number.

That number is printed on: **getMoney.php**.
On **index.php** i have the AJAX request.

Ajax Code:

```
function getMoney(selected)
        {
            if(selected.value != -1)
            {
                // Obtener presupuesto via AJAX
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "getMoney.php",
                            async: true,
                            success: function(datos){
                                //My action
                            }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

The function is called when I change a value on a Combobox HTML

```
<select name="area_id" onchange="getMoney(this);">
```

Well... My problem:
If i write down the numbers on getMoney.php (mannualy) its works perfectly, the AJAX's get it and the action is done, but when i get the numbers from my database i just get 0. I open mannualy too the getMoney.php, and the numbers ARE THERE! even if i get it from the Database.

What's wrong?

Comment: All of this is embeeded on my MVC, i simplified for undestanding, but the MVC is working right, i'ts a strange behavior of AJAX

Comment: can you post the code for getMoney.php ?

Comment: Your showing us the wrong section of code. We need the getMoney.php, and if you swear the number outputted is correct, whats in your AJAX success handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that getMoney.php is NOT using your standard view headers, i.e. script includes, stylesheet includes or anything else. Also, it's better practice to have getMoney.php to return a JSON string with your data parametized that way you can pull back diagnosic and error codes as well as specific data. this will help in debugging. look at [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) if you need help with that.

Comment: Exelent!! that worked for me! the JSON was the problem! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The XHR object will cache all request by the url, you can fix this by just appending a random string, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getMoney.php?r=" + new Date().getTime(),
    async: true,
    success: function(datos){
        //Your action
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery does this if you set `cache: false`.

Answer (score 0):

Install firebug plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/ in firefox.

Once you install the plugin, there will be a bug symbol in the right side of the status bar.

Click on it. Then change the select box. There will be a line in the firebug console.

There you can see all the data sent to the server and the response from the server. This will help you identify the issue.